# Editing/removing messages from ViewController

Tags: swift2, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have built a real-time database messenger in **Swift 2.3** using **Firebase 3.6.0** and **JSQMessagesViewController** pod.

At the moment I can send and receive messages from different devices that have the application installed from Xcode but unfortunately I'm unable to edit or remove the messages in the *MessengerViewController* where the **JSQMessagesViewController** pod is being used.

How can I go about doing this? I've included an example of my dilemma to further illustrate what my problem seems to be. I know I may have to do something with my Firebase database in my code to remove or edit these messages but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to go about doing it.

At the moment, the **only** way I can remove messages from the *MessengerViewController* is if I go into my database from my Firebase console and manually delete the data.

Also, I'm using the following pods:

- pod **'JSQMessagesViewController'**
- pod **'Firebase/Database'**
- pod **'Firebase/Auth'** (my application uses user authentication)
- pod **'Firebase/Core'**
- pod **'Firebase/Messaging'** (my application also includes cloud messaging to send push notifications from the Firebase console)

*I'm wondering if maybe I should've also used pod 'Firebase/Storage'*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a handle on to the message. This handle will trigger an action and since you triggered it off a specific message you can look the message up by `ID` and call the appropriate delete method to have firebase remove it from your database. But I would actually just suggest you tag the message as deleted and then if that tag exists on a message you do not display it client side. But that is really up to you.